# ERROR 403 - FORBIDDEN the server.php file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In the beatnikbd.com/fb-apps/nandos-app/ directory in Laravel 4, there is a file called server.php. The contents of this file look like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri))
{
    return true;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

But it show ERROR 403 - FORBIDDEN

Comment: Is the file having sufficient permission??

Comment: file permission given 644

Comment: Looks like everything in that dir gives 403, is it allowed by the webserver to access it? Anyway, 'server.php' is used when not on a webserver because it leverages the built-in php webserver

Answer (score 0):

Check if you set permissions of this file "server.php" to 755 ...

Comment: Is this eligible to be an answer??